# Scrapy symbol replace

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to delete symsol ":" from dates and it doesn't work:

```
 oper_dates=response.css('.textonline__date::text').extract()

 for item in oper_dates:
   clean_oper_date = item.replace(':', '')
```

oper_dates get data correctly but after replace I get empty csv. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place replaced result somewhere and save it at the end into csv:

```
 oper_dates=response.css('.textonline__date::text').extract()
 clean_oper_dates = []
 for item in oper_dates:
   clean_oper_date = item.replace(':', '')
   clean_oper_dates.append(clean_oper_date)
 
 # save clean_oper_dates into CSV
```